# Using a image service to put out random images with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

For the longest time ive been using a random message script to send image urls, people are complaining that there aren't that many images.

```
    @client.command()
    async def cat(ctx):
      embed=discord.Embed()
      embed.title='Here is a cat!'
      replies=['http://i.imgur.com/n4tx5v8.gifv','http://i.imgur.com/fs5S4vw.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/elito1b    .jpg','https://i.redd.it/5dp7mxriz9hy.jpg','https://i.redd.it/io3smelspnyy.jpg','http://i.imgur.com/v4JQtUi.gif','https://i.imgur.com/s3rgzi1.jpg','https://i.redd.it/irpkq0j3rlvy.jpg','https://i.redd.it/ltahcbtakg5z.jpg','http://i.imgur.com/zR0k0p5.gifv','https://i.redd.it/2p46o8wwrpky.jpg',]
embed.description=random.choice(replies)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Its very annoying to go out to places like imger and select random cat images, so I would want to use a image servicer to do it.

and im new to discord.py so if you could, could you make it as simple as simple as possible.

Comment: I reccomend imgurpython https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython for hosting images

Comment: You could web scrape a bunch of images imgur with beautifulsoup, that would probably be the best way. Or with selenium.

Comment: @maxmeinz Imgur has an API

Comment: ill have a look at the git @LuM

Comment: @LuM I didnt realize that, that would be the best way.

Comment: Actually I should probably take a look at that.

Comment: It says in readme.md 'The imgurpython project is no longer supported.' do you use it, if so does it work? @LuM

Comment: It is still working for my projects, but if imgur ever does some overhauls to the API, it might stop working. Otherwise, read into the API itself https://api.imgur.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here's code from a cog I use to fetch random cat images

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Embed
from aiohttp import ClientSession


async def get(session: object, url: object) -> object:
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()


class Image(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def cat(self, ctx):
        async with ClientSession() as session:
            url = await get(session, 'https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search')
            url = loads(url)[0]['url']
            await ctx.send(embed=Embed(
                title="", timestamp=dt.now(), url=url
            ).set_image(url=url))

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Image(bot))
```

Comment: 'commands' from 


     `class Image(commands.Cog):` 

isnt defined @InsertCheesyLine \

Comment: @Iharvested have you added the cog by adding the line `bot.load_extension('filename-without-.py')`